# Creating a grouped barchart in R, but with unique x values in each group?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Hopefully this isn't too obvious of an issue to solve or hasn't been asked yet.

I have data that is a much longer version of this:
| Publisher| Name | Sales|
| -------- | -----|----- |
| Nintendo | Aa   | 30   |
| Sony     | Ab   | 20   |
| EA       | Ac   | 20   |
| Nintendo | Ad   | 15   |
| Sony     | Ae   | 10   |
| Sony     | Af   | 20   |
| EA       | Ag   | 30   |

And I would like to make a bar chart similar to [this](https://miro.medium.com/max/464/1*5Dj8xkO55Xjac2emtiFgFQ.png), except I am searching for top five games for each of the top ten publishers.

This is the code I tried, but I find facet_wrap isn't what I want:

```
pubsales <- df%>%group_by(Publisher)%>%
  summarise(pubttlsale=sum(Sales))%>%
  top_n(10)%>%
  arrange(desc(pubttlsale))
df2 <- df%>%group_by(Publisher)%>%filter(Publisher%in%pubsales$Publisher)%>%
  summarise(pubttlsale=sum(Sales),Name,Publisher,Sales)%>%
  arrange(desc(pubttlsale))%>%
  top_n(5)
df2%>%ggplot(aes(x=Name,y=Sales))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  facet_grid(~Publisher)+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x="Game",y="Total Sales (millions of copies)")
```

Thank you for reading. Please tell me if I need to clarify more or provide more sample data (it's actually [this set](https://www.kaggle.com/rush4ratio/video-game-sales-with-ratings) from Kaggle).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `facet_wrap(~Publisher, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1, strip.position = "right")` which will put all publishers in one column, shows only the games per publisher and puts the script text on the right.

Note: To make the example both minimal and reproducible I used only the top 3 publishers and the top 4 games and added the data via `dput(df2)` See [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = Name, y = Sales)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Publisher, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1, strip.position = "right") +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = "Game", y = "Total Sales (millions of copies)")
```

[image]

To get more closer to the chart you posted as a link you could `reorder` the `Publisher`s by sales and make use of `tidy text::reorder_within` + `tidy text::scales_y_reorderd` to order `Name` by `Sales` per Publisher, make use of `geom_text` to put the publisher's name on the plot which allows to get rid of the strip texts and some additional styling.

Note: To simplify the code I make use of `geom_col` which is short for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` and switched the role of `x` and `y` to get rid of the `coord_flip`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(
    Publisher = reorder(Publisher, -Sales),
    Name = tidytext::reorder_within(Name, Sales, Publisher, fun = sum)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Publisher) %>% 
  mutate(y_label = Name[Name == last(Name)],
         label = ifelse(Name %in% y_label, as.character(Publisher), ""))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = Sales, y = Name, fill = Publisher)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(x = max(Sales), y = y_label, label = label), hjust = 1) +
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05))) +
  facet_wrap(~Publisher, scales = "free_y", ncol = 1) +
  labs(x = "Total Sales (millions of copies)", y = "Game") +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    strip.text = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df2 <- structure(list(Publisher = c(
  "Nintendo", "Nintendo", "Nintendo",
  "Nintendo", "Electronic Arts", "Electronic Arts", "Electronic Arts",
  "Electronic Arts", "Activision", "Activision", "Activision",
  "Activision"
), pubttlsale = c(
  1788.81, 1788.81, 1788.81, 1788.81,
  1116.96, 1116.96, 1116.96, 1116.96, 731.16, 731.16, 731.16, 731.16
), Name = c(
  "Wii Sports", "Super Mario Bros.", "Mario Kart Wii",
  "Wii Sports Resort", "FIFA 16", "FIFA Soccer 13", "The Sims 3",
  "Star Wars Battlefront (2015)", "Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3",
  "Call of Duty: Black Ops 3", "Call of Duty: Black Ops", "Call of Duty: Black Ops II"
), Sales = c(
  82.53, 40.24, 35.52, 32.77, 8.57, 8.16, 8.01, 7.98,
  14.73, 14.63, 14.61, 13.79
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually just figured this out myself, but I'm really grateful you answered so comprehensively.